# aws api gateway and lambda return new error status

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So when you create a new lambda from scracth you get the following default index.js inline code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!')
    };
    return response;
};
```

This lambda is used by an api gateway endpoint. What is the proper way to return an error code if something isn't quite right? Would the gateway handle it or should I just change the status above to a new error code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
1xx (Informational): The request was received, continuing process
2xx (Successful): The request was successfully received, understood, and accepted
3xx (Redirection): Further action needs to be taken in order to complete the request
4xx (Client Error): The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled
5xx (Server Error): The server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request
```

This is just returning a 200 response which is a successful response. You simply just need to return the correct code depending on the implementation you have. I think That is what you are asking for.

For more information on status code you can read this Wiki
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

But since you're asking about implementation I would do the following

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    let statusCode = 200;
    let message = 'success';
    ... // do stuff
    statusCode = 400 // something went wrong
    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        body: JSON.stringify(message)
    };
    return response;
};
```

It's really all up to you based on how you want your application to scale. Just remember, never duplicate code. Keep it modular.

Additionally you can also declare this in a function

```
// Somewhere else
response = function (statusCode, message) {
    return {
     statusCode: statusCode,
     body: JSON.stringify(message)
    };
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    let statusCode = 200;
    let message = 'success';
    ... // do stuff
    statusCode = 400 // something went wrong

    return response(statusCode, message);
};
```

Check out Error Handling Patterns from AWS.
It would be a good start unless you already read it.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/

Essentially you need something of the following

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var myErrorObj = {
        errorType : "InternalServerError",
        httpStatus : 500,
        requestId : context.awsRequestId,
        message : "An unknown error has occurred. Please try again."
    }
    callback(JSON.stringify(myErrorObj));
};
```

Comment: Updated OP with more info.

Comment: It's still sorta ambiguous what you're asking. Are you sending a 400 and getting a 200?

Comment: Right, I sent a 400 from Lambda but API gateway status shows 200. Although the API request body does reflect the 400.

Comment: That makes sense why it's doing that. Check the OA, see if that does something